# probablity expiring in the money ..basic question

Tags: options, black-scholes

Everyone says $N(d_2)$ is the probability of the option being exercised but stocks that have really high volatility have really expensive options indicating a high likelihood of expiring in the money. If volatility is very high we see that s $N(d_2)$  goes to 0, so doesn't that contradict our first statement? Isn't  $N(d_1)$ the true probability?

Comment: Please add definitions for N, d_1 and d_2. What is sN(d_2)? What is a true probability? What kind of option are you talking about?

Comment: Given the context of the question, N(.) is probably the CDF of the standard normal, with d1 and d2 defined as in the standard Black-Scholes formula.

Comment: If my answer was helpful I would encourage you to upvote and accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a very basic question. Please have a look at the following paper which will answer all your questions in a very intuitive and step-by-step fashion:

[Understanding $N(d_1)$ and $N(d_2)$: Risk-Adjusted Probabilities in the Black-Scholes Model by Lars Tyge Nielsen](http://www.ltnielsen.com/wp-content/uploads/Understanding.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @vonjd that the distinction between $N(d1)$ and $N(d2)$ is indeed a very basic question, which is why I upvoted his answer a long time ago. That said, reconciling why the probability of exercise for call options goes to zero when IVOL $\rightarrow \infty$, while at the same time you pay the discounted value of the forward $F=S_0e^{(r−q)T}$, which when the dividend yield is zero, corresponds to the current value of the stock price $S_0$, irrespective of strike, is not so trivial in my opinion.

The probabilities with increasing IVOL (3 = 300%):

[image]

Option values:

[image]

This indeed is looking a bit odd, and in my opinion, is best answered by looking at the probability density function (PDF) and cumulative density function (CDF).

The higher σ, the more the global maximum of the probability density function (the mode) shifts towards the lower bound of the lognormal distribution. On the other hand, as mentioned for example by @Jesper Tidblom,

> More and more contribution of the expected value come from values of
> $S_T$ when $S_T \geq K$ as $\sigma$ grows, although the probability
> for those values to occur goes to zero.  So we have a sort of
> competition of limits here where the values of $S_T$ above $K$
> increases faster than their probability to occur goes to zero, so to
> speak.

[image]

Also, expected returns decrease. Closely following the paper of [Lars Tyge Nielsen](https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Understanding.pdf) as referenced by @vonjd:

In `Black Scholes`, stock prices $S_t$ at time t follow a lognormal distribution. At time 0, $$log(S_T)  \sim \mathcal{N}(log(S) +(\mu -\sigma^2/2)t, \sigma^2t)$$
To be precise about $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ we need to make a few observations about the rate of return of the stock. The continuously compounded rate of return over an interval $[0,t]$ is $$\frac{log(S_t)-log(S)}{t}$$
Given the current stock price $S$, this rate follows the normal distribution $$\mathcal{N}((\mu -\sigma^2/2),\sigma^2/t) $$
In plain English, its logarithm is normally distributed with mean $(\mu -\sigma^2/2)$ and variance $\sigma^2/t$. As $t$ grows, variance decreases towards zero, whereas the mean of the rate of return does not depend on time $t$. However, the mean depends on volatility. The chart below shows this relationship for a unit interval ($t=1$).

[image]

This can also be demonstrated by plotting the PDF of the normal distirbution.
[image]

Last but not least, the cumulated distribution function (CDF) shows the increase in the probability of $S_T$ being very small.

[image]

Therefore, the probability of exercise for a call eventually becomes zero. At the same time, the expected value of $S_T$ being above K increases faster, making the option approaching its maximum value.

Ultimately, limits can be a strange thing. Warren Buffett explained his take on the Black Scholes formula for long-dated options (which has a similar effect as large IVOL) in his [2008 letter to the Shareholders of Berkshire Hathaway](https://www.berkshirehathaway.com/letters/2008ltr.pdf).

> The Black-Scholes formula has approached the status of holy writ in
> finance, and we use it when valuing our equity put options for
> financial statement purposes. ... If the formula is applied to
> extended time periods, however, it can produce absurd results. In
> fairness, Black and Scholes almost certainly understood this point
> well.