# Bachelier model call: computation of delta of a call option

Tags: options, delta-hedging, call

The price of a call with a stock with Bachellier process as its underlying and zero interest rate is giving by:
$$C(t)=(S(t)-K)\Phi(\frac{S(t)-K}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}})+\sigma \sqrt{T-t} \phi(\frac{S(t)-K}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}})$$
**How do I compute/derive/proof the time $t$ Delta-hedge ratio: hence compute $dC(t)/dS(t)$?**

I have tried to reach to the delta by looking at the answers to this question: [Bachelier option delta = probability of exercise?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31993/bachelier-option-delta-probability-of-exercise)
but there's some differentiation in there which is not clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero interest rate and drift so $S(T) = S(t) + \sigma (W(T)-W(t))$ and $\frac{d S(T)}{dS(t)} = 1.
$
$$
C(t) = E_t[(S(T) - K)^+]
$$
$$
\frac{dC(t)}{dS(t)} = \frac{d}{dS(t)} E_t[(S(T) - K)^+] 
= E_t[\frac{d}{dS(t)} (S(T) - K)^+] = E_t[\frac{d S(T)}{dS(t)} \text{Indicator}(S(T) > K)]=  E_t[\text{Indicator}(S(T) > K)]=  \text{Prob}_t[S(T) > K]=\Phi(\frac{S(t)-K}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}})
$$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dS(t)} E_t[(S(T)-K)\textbf{1}_{S(T) > K}]= E_t[\frac{d}{dS(t)}(S(T)-K)\textbf{1}_{S(T) > K}]$... This is indirect application of Leibniz, right? In that case; we need to ensure contuinuty. As far as I know: $(S(T)-K)\textbf{1}_{S(T) > K}$ is not contnous?

Comment: I forgot to tag you before just wanted to make sure if you see the comment

Comment: Yes. $x \mapsto (x-K)^+$ is continuous and differentiable. The derivative is discontinuous but it does not matter.

Comment: It does not appear correct that $\frac{d}{dS(t)}(S(T)-K)\pmb{1}_{S(T)>K} = \pmb{1}_{S(T)>K}$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dS(t)} (S(T)-K)1_{S(T)>K} = \frac{dS(T)}{dS(t)} 1_{S(T)>K}$

Comment: However, $\frac{dS(T)}{dS(t)} \ne 1$, assuming that $S(T)\ne S(t)$.

Comment: In the Bachelier model $\frac{dS(T)}{dS(t)}=1$. See answer.