# European Swaption Pricing Using Normal volatilities

Tags: programming, swaption

On page 6 of [this paper](https://uk.milliman.com/uploadedFiles/insight/2015/2079LDP_20150911.pdf) a forumla is given for payer swaptions, I am just wondering what is the formula for receiver?

My implementation of the formula for payer and receiver is [here](https://github.com/paragonhao/AFPSwaptionCalibration/blob/master/normalModel.py), but I am not very sure about it.

Also to get ATM swaption, does that mean the forward swap rate is equal to the strike price?

Comment: for some reasons, the first link does not work

Comment: The editor of the post made a mistake, I have corrected it now

Answer (score 4):

The formula for pricing a swaption under normal volatility is simply the Bachelier formula. It may be found in many papers (for example, Le Floc'h [Fast and accurate basis point volatility](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2420757)), and is also on [stackoverflow](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38897/bachelier-model-call-computation-of-delta-of-a-call-option).

You can easily move from a payer ($C$) to a receiver ($P$) by using the put-call parity relationship:
$$ C(t) - P(t) = B(t,T) (F(t,T)-K)\,,$$

where $B$ is the discount factor to maturity, $F$ the forward rate, $K$ the strike.

The formula in your python code looks correct to me, in accordance with the [first reference](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2420757).

Comment: Thanks! A quick follow up question - For ATM Swaption, does this mean the forward rate is equal to the strike? If thats the case, with the formula you have provided above, the difference between a payer and receiver is zero?

Comment: ATM spot or forward premia are typically quoted as a straddle (receiver + payer) where both payer and receiver have the same price due to the parity states above. ATMF r ate is indeed the forward rate of the underlying swap.